# how to setup a kinect available environment

Tags: ros, kinect, openni, nite

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 and ROS electric.
To make a Kinect available,
All I have to do is just "sudo apt-get install ros-electric-openni-kinect", is it?

About OpenCV, I've must install OpenCV alone.
How about OpenNI, driver for a Kinect and NITE?
And do I need plug a Kinect to my PC during installations?

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32783/how-to-setup-a-kinect-available-environment/) by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 721 on 2012-04-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If your installation of ROS is correct, you only need:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-electric-openni-kinect
```

But you can find this information here: http://ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect, too. There is no need to plug a Kinect to your PC during the installations (Ubuntu isn't Windows).

I'm not sure about your question related to OpenCV. If you compile OpenCV from source, you have to use cmake, where you can activate the OpenNI support. You have to take care about the dependencies of OpenCV, but you will get a error message from cmake if something is missing.

---

Originally posted by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) with karma: 1480 on 2012-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0